# DataGridView Mousedown and Mouseup cell background color change doesn't work

Tags: c#, datagridview

On my C# datagridview, I want the user to be acknowledged that they have indeed clicked on the cell.

I am using the datagridview's MouseDown and MouseUp events. The code functions correctly for the MouseDown event, by changing the cell color to Blue, but the MouseUp event does not change the color of the cell back to Transparent.

The resulting function is that all the cells I click on turn Blue, and stay Blue.

Am I not calling the Refresh method correctly? Is there a better way to achieve the same thing?

Here is my code:

```
private void Selector_dataGridView_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridViewCellStyle CellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
            CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Blue;
            Selector_dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style = CellStyle;
            Selector_dataGridView.Refresh();
        }

        private void Selector_dataGridView_CellMouseUp(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridViewCellStyle CellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
            CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            Selector_dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style = CellStyle;
            Selector_dataGridView.Refresh();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need just a line in `MouseDown`:

```
Selector_dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style.SelectionBackColor = Color.Blue;
```

And revert back in `MouseUp`:

```
Selector_dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style.SelectionBackColor = Color.White;
```

Comment: This worked. It looks like I have to use Color.White, I cannot use Color.Empty or Color.Transparent. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your Selector_dataGridView_CellMouseUp event, try changing the color to empty instead of transparent:

```
CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Empty;
```

Comment: Its now changed the behaviour, but still not quite right. The cell correctly goes to "Empty" when I click on another cell. So there is a lag of one step. My Refresh function isn't correctly called. Am I using Refresh correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The cell mouse up handler will fire on whichever cell the mouse pointer is over at that time. I'm assuming you are moving you mouse away from the clicked cell after clicking. I would suggest clearing/refreshing all cells to transparent on mouseup but which will be a little overkill if you are dealing with a lot of cells.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellmouseup(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I put a breakpoint on the mouseup event, it is referencing the correct row and column index. I suspect the Refresh method I am calling is being used incorrectly. Its some how not repainting on the mouseup, but only mousedown.